# Remove item from nested dictionaries if specified key contains None values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries in which I am trying to remove any dictionary should the value of a certain key is None, it will be removed.

```
item_dict = [
    {'code': 'aaa0000',
     'id': 415294,
     'index_range': '10-33',
     'location': 'A010',
     'type': 'True'},
    {'code': 'bbb1458',
     'id': 415575,
     'index_range': '30-62',
     'location': None,
     'type': 'True'},
    {'code': 'ccc3013',
     'id': 415575,
     'index_range': '14-59',
     'location': 'C041',
     'type': 'True'}
    ]


for item in item_dict:
    filtered = dict((k,v) for k,v in item.iteritems() if v is not None)


# Output Results
# Item - aaa0000 is missing
# {'index_range': '14-59', 'code': 'ccc3013', 'type': 'True', 'id': 415575, 'location': 'C041'}
```

In my example, the output result is missing one of the dictionary and if I tried to create a new list to append `filtered`, item `bbb1458` will be included in the list as well.

How can I rectify this?

Comment: You constantly (each iteration) overwrite filtered.

Comment: Your question says you want to remove things "if a certain key is None", but your sample code removes things if _any_ value is None, not just a certain key's value. Which one do you want?

Comment: Your question also says you want to remove a whole dictionary if that certain key's value is None, but your sample code instead returns a copy of the dictionary with that key-value pair removed. Again, which one do you want?

Comment: @abarnert Pardon me for not being specified, I have edited the title. I wanted to remove the dictionary if a specified key value is found to be None

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[item for item in item_dict if None not in item.values()]
```

Each item in this list is a dictionary. And a dictionary is only appended to this list if `None` does not appear in the dictionary values.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Say in the event say if item `aaa0000` key `index_range` is also `None`, wouldn't your solution removes aaa0000 dictionary too? Can I narrow it down such that it will be checking on a specified key, in this case `location`?

Comment: Yes `[item for item in item_dict if item[location] != None]`, this assumes your dictionaries all have this special `location` key though. If some dictionaries don't have this key, there will be a `KeyError`.

Comment: you can use `has_key(...) and` to get past the `KeyError` if valid dicts can exclude that key.

Comment: @TemporalWolf note that `has_key(...)` has been removed from python 3 and will throw an `AttributeError` if you try to use it in python 3. In python 3 it would have to be `[... if 'location' in item and item['location'] != None]` in order to keep the dictionary if the key 'location' does not appear. It's not clear what the desired behavior is if the specified key does not appear though.

Comment: Thank you all, this is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new list using a list comprehension, filtering on the condition that all values are not `None`:

```
item_dict = [
    {'code': 'aaa0000',
     'id': 415294,
     'index_range': '10-33',
     'location': 'A010',
     'type': 'True'},
    {'code': 'bbb1458',
     'id': 415575,
     'index_range': '30-62',
     'location': None,
     'type': 'True'},
    {'code': 'ccc3013',
     'id': 415575,
     'index_range': '14-59',
     'location': 'C041',
     'type': 'True'}
    ]

filtered = [d for d in item_dict if all(value is not None for value in d.values())]
print(filtered)

#[{'index_range': '10-33', 'id': 415294, 'location': 'A010', 'type': 'True', 'code': 'aaa0000'}, {'index_range': '14-59', 'id': 415575, 'location': 'C041', 'type': 'True', 'code': 'ccc3013'}]
```